# Change the value of a data frame when is clicked in a datatable

Tags: r, dataframe, shiny, shinydashboard, dt

Im trying make some similar a inbox in R. I have a data frame of messages and i show it in a table of `DT` libray and in a `messageItem` of `shinydashboard` library. I would like when you click on a message in the table change "leido" value to TRUE.

I have this code

**Data frame**

```
from <- c("A","B","C")
content <- c("Mensaje 1","Mensaje2","Mensaje leido")
leido <- c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE)
messages <- data.frame(from,content,leido)
```

**DT::datatableoutput of messages**

```
output$tablaMensajes <- DT::renderDataTable({
    messages
})
```

**Message item output**

```
output$mensajes <- renderMenu({
    msgs <- apply(messages[which(messages$leido == FALSE),], 1, function(row) {
        messageItem(from = row[["from"]], message = row[["content"]],href = paste0("javascript:mensaje('",row[["content"]],"')"))
    })
     dropdownMenu(type = "messages", .list = msgs)
})
```

I make a observe event when a row is clicked, this change the value of cell, but when i cliked i another row the change don´t save.

**Observe event**

```
observe({
    if(! is.null(input$tablaMensajes_rows_selected)){
        messages
        s<-input$tablaMensajes_rows_selected
        messages[s,"leido"] = TRUE
        output$mensajes <- renderMenu({
        msgs <- apply(messages[which(messages$leido == FALSE),], 1, function(row) {
                messageItem(from = row[["from"]], message = row[["content"]],href = paste0("javascript:mensaje('",row[["content"]],"')"))
            })
            dropdownMenu(type = "messages", .list = msgs)
        })


    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code. I am guessing this is what you want:

```
    library(shiny)
    library(shinydashboard)
    library(DT)

    from <- c("A","B","C")
    content <- c("Mensaje 1","Mensaje2","Mensaje leido")
    leido <- c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE)
    messages <- data.frame(from,content,leido)

    ui <- dashboardPage(
      dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic sidebar"),
      dashboardSidebar(
        sidebarMenuOutput("mensajes")
      ),
      dashboardBody( DT::dataTableOutput("tablaMensajes"))
    )


    server = function(input, output, session){

      output$tablaMensajes <- DT::renderDataTable({
        messages
      })


      output$mensajes <- renderMenu({
        msgs <- apply(messages[which(messages$leido == FALSE),], 1, function(row) {
          messageItem(from = row[["from"]], message = row[["content"]],href = paste0("javascript:mensaje('",row[["content"]],"')"))
        })
        dropdownMenu(type = "messages", .list = msgs)
      })

      observe({
        if(! is.null(input$tablaMensajes_rows_selected)){
          #browser()
          messages
          s<-input$tablaMensajes_rows_selected
          messages[s,"leido"] <<- TRUE
          output$mensajes <- renderMenu({
            msgs <- apply(messages[which(messages$leido == FALSE),], 1, function(row) {
              messageItem(from = row[["from"]], message = row[["content"]],href = paste0("javascript:mensaje('",row[["content"]],"')"))
            })
            dropdownMenu(type = "messages", .list = msgs)
          })


          output$tablaMensajes <- DT::renderDataTable({
            messages
          })


        }
      })

    }

    shinyApp(ui,server)


**[EDIT]:**

To remove subscript out of bound error I have edited the above code to add conditions if the no rows with false value is present then the message should be be empty. 

library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(DT)

from <- c("A","B","C")
content <- c("Mensaje 1","Mensaje2","Mensaje leido")
leido <- c(FALSE,FALSE,TRUE)
messages <- data.frame(from,content,leido)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dynamic sidebar"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenuOutput("mensajes")
  ),
  dashboardBody( DT::dataTableOutput("tablaMensajes"))
)


server = function(input, output, session){

  output$tablaMensajes <- DT::renderDataTable({
    messages
  })


  output$mensajes <- renderMenu({
    if(nrow(messages[which(messages$leido == FALSE),]) >0) {
      msgs <- apply(messages[which(messages$leido == FALSE),], 1, function(row) {
        messageItem(from = row[["from"]], message = row[["content"]],href = paste0("javascript:mensaje('",row[["content"]],"')"))
      }) 
    }else{
      msgs = NULL
    }

    dropdownMenu(type = "messages", .list = msgs)
  })

  observe({
    if(! is.null(input$tablaMensajes_rows_selected)){
      #browser()
      messages
      s<-input$tablaMensajes_rows_selected
      messages[s,"leido"] <<- TRUE
      output$mensajes <- renderMenu({
        if(nrow(messages[which(messages$leido == FALSE),]) >0) {
        msgs <- apply(messages[which(messages$leido == FALSE),], 1, function(row) {
          messageItem(from = row[["from"]], message = row[["content"]],href = paste0("javascript:mensaje('",row[["content"]],"')"))
        })
        }else{
          msgs = NULL
        }
        dropdownMenu(type = "messages", .list = msgs)
      })


      output$tablaMensajes <- DT::renderDataTable({
        messages
      })


    }
  })

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: it works fine but when i havent menssages without read the messageItem return this error , `Error: subscript out of bounds`

Comment: I have edited the code to remove the error. The error was there because the number of rows with false would be zero.